# ASP.NET MVC and Model Binding?

Tags: asp.net, html, asp.net-mvc

In my effort to convert few asp.net webforms into MVC razor views, I have converted all server side controls into equivalent HTML tags.

I am a bit late to realise that I should have used MVC HTML helpers, The issue here is I am not able to bind HTML tags values to strongly typed view request.

Is there any way in MVC-3 to map Model properties with HTML tags, without using HTML helpers?

```
Consider following Model class:
class Person
{
    public string FirstName{get; set;}
}
View
@model MyApplication.Models.Person

<input type="text" id="txtFirstName" **???**/>
```

In place of `???` I am expecting some attribute here to bind input to `FirstName` property of Model.

Is it feasible ?

Comment: Not sure to understand completely your question but you have a complete freedom in mvc3 to inter-relate the input of your choice with any property on your model using the controller

Comment: Hard to give you an answer with this question. I would say yes, but I think it would make sense to give us a sample case...

Comment: Just to answer the question title, no it is not mandatory to use Html helpers. If you look at the markup all the html helpers do is format your <input> tags

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [DefaultModelBinder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.defaultmodelbinder%28v=vs.98%29.aspx) is using the `name` attribute to bind values from the HTTP request to your model. If this convention doesn't suit your needs, you can write your own ModelBinder.

So in your case the following code should work (but I would recommend using HTML helpers anyway, because with HTML helper you can use automatic unobtrusive validation)

**Controller:**

```
public ActionResult Create(Person person) {
  ...
}
```

**View:**

```
@model MyApplication.Models.Person

<input type="text" id="txtFirstName" name="FirstName" />
```

Comment: thank you, this helped for twitter bootstrap date picker